# What is a more effective way to write this?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops, optimization

Workbook contains a summary worksheet and a random number of estimate worksheets. This sub populates the summary worksheet with a manual update button. Most of the data are in known, fixed cells. Some data are in a random row on the estimate worksheets. I'm using a function to find those rows. This sub runs slowly, and I'm sure this is the 'sledgehammer' method. Should I write the cell values to an array first and then paste in the summary sheet? Or other, better methods?

```
Sub UpdateSummary()
    Call ParaOff
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim name As String
    j = 5
    Call HideX
    Call SortWorksheets
    If Not WorksheetExists(wsF) Then
        MsgBox "ERROR: Worksheet '" & wsF & "' is missing."
    Else
        'Sheets(wsF).Activate
        Worksheets(wsF).Range("B7:U41").ClearContents
        Worksheets(wsF).Range("W7:W41").ClearContents
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            If Worksheets(i).name <> wsF And Worksheets(i).name <> wsG And Worksheets(i).name <> wsI And Worksheets(i).name <> wsJ And Worksheets(i).name <> wsK Then
                Worksheets(i).Range("S1").Copy 'PROJECT
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("B" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("J6").Copy 'LOCATION
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("C" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("Q1").Copy 'DURATION
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("D" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("M1").Copy 'PROJECT TOTAL
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("E" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("S10").Copy 'MISC %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("F" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("S11").Copy 'MISC $
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("G" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("N10").Copy 'OTHER %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("H" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("N11").Copy 'OTHER $
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("I" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("P13").Copy 'GC TOTAL
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("J" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("K11").Copy 'GC %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("K" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("L11").Copy 'GC DAY
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("L" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("M11").Copy 'GC MONTH
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("M" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("S14").Copy 'PM %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("N" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("K14").Copy 'PM HRS
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("O" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("S16").Copy 'SUPER %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("P" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("K16").Copy 'SUPER HRS
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("Q" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("S18").Copy 'PE %
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("R" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("K18").Copy 'PE HRS
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("S" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Worksheets(i).Range("Q10").Copy 'CARP HRS
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("T" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                x = fFindRowByCol(Worksheets(i).name, "I", "Div 26*")
                Worksheets(i).Range("P" & x).Copy 'DIV 26 $
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("U" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                x = fFindRowByCol(Worksheets(i).name, "I", "Div 32*")
                Worksheets(i).Range("P" & x).Copy 'DIV 32 $
                Worksheets(wsF).Range("W" & j + i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Call ParaOn
    Call Happy
End Sub
```

Comment: they are  specific worksheet names: `Private Const wsF As String = "SUMMARY"
Private Const wsG As String = "z BLANK x"`

Comment: Don'ţ use the clipboard, i.e. `Worksheets(wsF).Range("B" & j + i).Value = Worksheets(i).Range("S1").Value` etc.

Comment: @SpectralInstance, this change reduced the calculation time for a sample run from 1.5s to 0.2s. Thank you. I'll try VBasic2008's solution as well, later today.

Answer (score 2):

### Get Rid of Long Repetitive Lines

... by using variables and data structures (e.g. arrays, dictionaries (collections))...

**Description**

- This code updates a summary worksheet in a workbook by copying and pasting data from other worksheets in the workbook.

**The Code**

```vb
Sub UpdateSummary()
    ' PROJECT, LOCATION,  DURATION, PROJECT TOTAL, MISC %,   MISC $, OTHER %,
    ' OTHER $, GC TOTAL,  GC %,     GC DAY,        GC MONTH, PM %,   PM HRS,
    ' SUPER %, SUPER HRS, PE %,     PE HRS,        CARP HRS
    
    ' Define constants.
    Dim sCells(): sCells = VBA.Array( _
        "S1", "J6", "Q1", "M1", "S10", "S11", "N10", _
        "N11", "P13", "K11", "L11", "M11", "S14", "K14", _
        "S16", "K16", "S18", "K18", "Q10")
    Dim dCols(): dCols = VBA.Array( _
        "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", _
        "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", _
        "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T")
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 6
    
    ' ???
    Call ParaOff
    Call HideX
    Call SortWorksheets
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to reference the destination worksheet (instead of the function).
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dws = wb.Worksheets(wsF)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dws Is Nothing Then
        
        MsgBox "ERROR: Worksheet '" & wsF & "' is missing.", vbCritical
    
    Else
        
        dws.Range("B7:U41", "W7:W41").ClearContents
        
        ' Write the names of the worksheets to be excluded to a dictionary.
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        ' These worksheet names should be in an array.
        dict(wsF) = Empty
        dict(wsG) = Empty
        dict(wsI) = Empty
        dict(wsJ) = Empty
        dict(wsK) = Empty
        
        ' Write the first row to a variable.
        Dim dRow As Long: dRow = DST_FIRST_ROW
        
        Dim sws As Worksheet, sRow As Long, n As Long
        
        For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
            ' Check if it's not a worksheet from the dictionary.
            If Not dict.Exists(sws.Name) Then
                ' Normal case.
                For n = 0 To UBound(sCells)
                    dws.Range(dRow, dCols(n)).Value = sws.Range(sCells(n)).Value
                Next n
                ' ??? Special case.
                sRow = fFindRowByCol(sws.Name, "I", "Div 26*")
                dws.Cells(dRow, "U").Value = sws.Cells(sRow, "P").Value 'DIV 26
                sRow = fFindRowByCol(sws.Name, "I", "Div 32*")
                dws.Cells(dRow, "W").Value = sws.Cells(sRow, "P").Value 'DIV 32
                dRow = dRow + 1 ' increment for the next iteration (worksheet)
            End If
        Next sws
    
    End If
    
    ' ???
    Call ParaOn
    Call Happy

    MsgBox "Summary updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**The Flow**

- The code first defines constants for the cell ranges and columns to be copied and clears the contents of the destination worksheet.
- It then creates a dictionary of worksheet names to be excluded from the copying process, and loops through all worksheets in the workbook, copying and pasting the data from the specified cells into the corresponding columns on the destination worksheet, except for the excluded worksheets.
- There are also two special cases where data is copied from specific cells on the source worksheet to specific columns on the destination worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

OK but the solution, or the answer was just in a comment, there was no checkmark to check as an answer. So many rules here! Posting my problem here and getting a solution was both incredibly helpful and a learning opportunity for my coding.